# How to change shell flyout behavior of Android to be same as to IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

The behavior of the navigation experience between flyout and detail pages is platform dependent:

- On iOS, the detail page slides to the right as the flyout page slides
  from the left, and the left part of the detail page is still visible.
- On Android, the detail and flyout pages are overlaid on each other.
- On UWP, the flyout page slides from the left over part of the detail
  page, provided that the FlyoutLayoutBehavior property is set to
  Popover. It it the deault behavior of different platform which we
  could not change

I need a custom renderer for Xamarin Shell that changes the behaviour of Android to be similar to IOS one.
Uploaded sample code

public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}

```
    protected override IShellFlyoutContentRenderer CreateShellFlyoutContentRenderer()
    {
        //var flyoutContentRenderer = base.CreateShellFlyoutContentRenderer();
        //var flyoutbackground = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(Platform.CurrentActivity, Resource.Drawable.flyoutbackground);

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //flyoutbackground.SetColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(
            //    Shell.Current.FlyoutBackgroundColor.ToAndroid(), BlendMode.Color));
            //flyoutContentRenderer.AndroidView.SetBackground(flyoutbackground);
        }
        else
        {
            //flyoutbackground.SetColorFilter(Shell.Current.FlyoutBackgroundColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Src);
            //flyoutContentRenderer.AndroidView.SetBackgroundDrawable(flyoutbackground);
        }
        //return flyoutContentRenderer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tryed this . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage#control-the-detail-page-layout-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the `FlyoutPage` manages the flyout and detail pages depends on whether the application is running on a phone or tablet, the orientation of the device, and the value of the [FlyoutLayoutBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flyoutpage.flyoutlayoutbehavior?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-flyoutpage-flyoutlayoutbehavior) property. This property determines how the detail page will be displayed. It's possible values are:

- **Default** – The pages are displayed using the platform default.
- **Popover** – The detail page covers, or partially covers the flyout
  page.
- **Split** – The flyout page is displayed on the left and the detail page
  is on the right.
- **SplitOnLandscape** – A split screen is used when the device is in
  landscape orientation.
- **SplitOnPortrait** – A split screen is used when the device is in
  portrait orientation.

The following XAML code example demonstrates how to set the `FlyoutLayoutBehavior` property on a FlyoutPage:

```
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.MainPage"
            FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover">
  ...
</FlyoutPage>
```

Note:

The value of the `FlyoutLayoutBehavior` property only affects applications running on tablets or the desktop. Applications running on phones always have the `Popover` behavior.

For more information, you can refer to document: [Control the detail page layout behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage#control-the-detail-page-layout-behavior).

Comment: Well, does it change the approach for Android because I made a flyout page and still the same

Comment: From the document I posted, we know that `The value of the FlyoutLayoutBehavior property only affects applications running on tablets or the desktop. Applications running on phones always have the Popover behavior.` .